# Magento 2 Autoload error after moving site on live domain

Tags: magento2, error, migration, composer

I set up my site on my test server and after moving it to my live domain, its giving me

```
Autoload error

Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.
```

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: is your issue solved?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by running command

```
  composer install
```

in magento directory.

Comment: quelle surprise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before run "composer install" show me this below

Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.1.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.0 requires theseer/fdomdocument ~1.4 -> satisfiable by theseer/fdomdocument[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6].
    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.